# EXTJS 5: Load child Nodes from the server on expand(TreePanel, load on demand)

Tags: extjs5

I have a tree, which only loads 3 level at a time.
So when a user click on expand on a node, `extjs` will call a service and populate with the leaf nodes of that node. How can I acchieve this? For now, i'm only able to load all of the nodes at once, which is a huge performance hit if there is lot of nodes.

**Model**:

```
Ext.define("TreePanelResult", {    
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
    fields: [
             { name: "orgId", type: "int"},
             { name: "orgName", type: "string"},
             { name: "OrgShortName", type : "string"},
             { name: "iconCls", type: "string"},
             { name: "leaf", type: "bool" }
          ],
    idProperty:'orgId'

});
```

**ViewModel**:

```
Ext.define('SampleViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.sampleTreeModel',
    stores: {
        treeStore: {
            type: 'tree',
            model:TreePanelResult,
            root: {
                text: 'Org', 
                id:'src',
                expanded: true,
                orgId: -1
            },
            paramNode:'orgId',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'services/admin/getHirerachy',
                reader : {
                    type : 'json',
                    rootProperty : 'systemChildNodes'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                beforeload: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
                    operation.params.node = operation.node.get("orgId");
                    store.getProxy().setExtraParams("orgId", operation.node.get("orgId"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**JSON Stucture:**

```
 {    
        "status": true,
        children:null,
        "systemChildNodes": [
        {
            "orgId": "234334",
            "orgParentId": "0",
            "OrgShortName": "csdsdsd",
            "iconCls": "",
            "leaf": false,
            "systemChildNodes": [
                {
                    "orgId": "2345446",
                    "orgParentId": "234334",
                    "OrgShortName": "sdewew",
                    "iconCls": "",
                    "leaf": false,
                    "systemChildNodes": []
                }
                {
                    "orgId": "2345446",
                    "orgParentId": "234334",
                    "OrgShortName": "sdewew",
                    "iconCls": "",
                    "leaf": false,
                    "systemChildNodes": []
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Sankar.